# Got `UnboundLocalError` error when measuring time for `torch.where`

Tags: python, time, error-handling, pytorch

When try to `%timeit` in Jupyter Notebook got error; Without it working fine.

> `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

```py
import torch
a = torch.rand(10)
b = torch.rand(10)
```

```
%timeit a = torch.where(b > 0.5, torch.tensor(0.), a)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipython %timeit "local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269712/ipython-timeit-local-variable-a-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought that's because `%timeit` only evaluates the time run by functions. But thanks to @Shiva who told me it can calculate the execution time of other things. And I checked the documentation [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), and I found out this is true.

So, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58164399/5612363), `%timeit` has a problem with re-assignment as the re-assignment to `a` causes the function to have an `a` local variable, hiding the global. In other words, you can use any other variable other that `a` to assign it to `torch.where`:

```
#this works
%timeit c = torch.where(b > 0.5, torch.tensor(0.), a) #c instead of a

# this works
%timeit torch.where(b > 0.5, torch.tensor(0.), a)

# this doesn't work
%timeit a = torch.where(b > 0.5, torch.tensor(0.), a)
```

Comment: The argument to `%timeit` need not be a function, it can be any expression or statement(including a function statement)

Comment: yeah... you're right. I didn't know that till now. Gonna edit my answer. Thanks